# Orbstack Docker Daemon not being used when building/running docker containers on MacOS

Tags: docker, macos, containers, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

I installed Orbstack to replace Docker Desktop on MacOS. Shutting Docker Desktop off and running Orbstack, I am trying to build and run docker containers but am getting the following message:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/[user-name]/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I see that the Orbstack Docker daemon directory is `/Users/acarella/.orbstack/run/docker.sock`, and there is this symlink in `/var/run/`: `docker.sock -> /Users/[user-name]/.orbstack/run/docker.sock`, but this doesn't seem to be used.

Seems like I have to get the Docker daemon to use `/Users/[user-name]/.orbstack/run/` instead of `/Users/[user-name]/.docker/run/` but can't figure out how to do that. Orbstack's documentation seems to suggest that replacing Docker Desktop with Orbstack should do a lot of this automatically but this seems to be something that was missed on my computer. How can I resolve this so I can use Orbstack's Docker daemon for my containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symlink needs to point *from* the socket Orbstack Docker Daemon is trying to link to (`/Users/[user-name]/.docker/run/docker.sock`), to the actual socket location (`/Users/[user-name]/.orbstack/run/docker.sock`)

For example:

```bash
sudo ln -s /Users/[user-name]/.orbstack/run/docker.sock /Users/[user-name]/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

Then restart the Orbstack Docker daemon and see if this helped.